# Route-map changing from permit to deny retains the match tag values

Tags: cisco, route, ios, mapping

I have a route-map configured on my cisco router with name say s1 and sequence number 10(default) which contains a match tag 10. If i again try to configure the same route-map name with same sequence number 10 (default) with a newer match tag 20 it is actually appending the match tag 20 with 10. Is it expected. since I have changed from permit to deny should it not flush out previous values ???

R1(config)#route-map s1 per
R1(config)#route-map s1 permit
R1(config-route-map)#mat
R1(config-route-map)#match tag
R1(config-route-map)#match tag 10
R1(config-route-map)#do sh route-map
route-map s1, permit, sequence 10
  Match clauses:
    tag 10
  Set clauses:
  Policy routing matches: 0 packets, 0 bytes
R1(config-route-map)#exit
R1(config)#route
R1(config)#route-
R1(config)#route-map s1 deny
R1(config)#route-map s1 deny
R1(config-route-map)#match
R1(config-route-map)#match tag
R1(config-route-map)#match tag 20
R1(config-route-map)#do sh route-map
route-map s1, deny, sequence 10
  Match clauses:
    tag 10 20
  Set clauses:
  Policy routing matches: 0 packets, 0 bytes
R1(config-route-map)#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - this is expected.  A given sequence number can be either a permit or deny and changing from one to the other doesn't eliminate the contents.  As to the contents themselves (i.e. match statements) you're essentially telling the route-map to perform a logical OR on the two tags.  If you want to only match on 20 then you should issue "no route-map s1 permit  10"